# Is it possible to define a class's response to implicit casting attempts?

Tags: c#, casting, implicit-conversion

For my class `foo`, if I try to do this:

```
public foo ClassName = new foo();
public string MyString = ClassName;
```

I will get an obvious error, as ClassName is not a String.

Is there a way to force the behavior of a class in such cases? Something along the lines of:

```
WhenCalledAsString {return self.ToString()}
```

Comment: `public static implicit operator String(ClassName value) {...}`

Comment: You could simple use `.GetType().Name` on your `ClassName` object.

Comment: Be careful and wary about implicit conversion operators, though. C#'s rules for overload resolution mean that such conversions can happen in quite unexpected places. In most cases, especially for string conversion, you should rely on methods (i.e. override `Object.ToString()` and call it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should implement an `implict operator`, e.g.:

```
public class foo {
  ....

  public static implicit operator string(foo value) {
    if (null == value)
      return null;

    //TODO: put relevant code here, e.g. value.ToString()
    return "it's a foo class!";
  }
}
```

Then you can put

```
public foo ClassName = new foo();

// "it's a foo class!";
public string MyString = ClassName;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could override `ToString` and define an implicit operator like this:

```
public class foo
{
    public static implicit operator string(foo f)
    {  
        return f.ToString();
    } 

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "hello!";
    }
}
```

Then call it (for example) like this:

```
public static foo ClassName = new foo();

public static void Main()
{
    string MyString = ClassName;

    Console.WriteLine(MyString);  // hello!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pizza pizza = new Pizza();
        string test = pizza;
    }
}

public class Pizza
{
    public static implicit operator string(Pizza pizza)
    {
        return pizza?.ToString();
    }
}
```

Output:

> Namespace.Pizza

---

Side note after edit:

It supports even `null` values!

Comment: I suggest adding check for `null`; since in case of `Pizza pizza = null; string test = pizza;` I expect `string test == null;` without any exceptions thrown.

Comment: I did return pizza?.ToString(); to solve the problem, thank you for the tip!